# Could sophonts that evolved in colder climates keep cool in the tropics with simple technology?

Tags: fantasy-races, humanoid

On an Earth-like planet, we have a functionally human-like creature which evolved to dwell comfortably in its world's boreal forests. As humans have done, it will likely have a desire to explore its world and find new places to live

This raises the question of temperature: Unlike with humans, there are many places on the globe much hotter than their natural environment, which seems to require that they'd cool themselves down. I am specifically interested in their early history, so they should have Bronze-Age level technology at most

Could these sophonts manage to substantially cool themselves enough to survive in hotter areas like the tropics with the technology that they have access to?

Comment: Do you have a goal with this question? Humans have lived in deserts (areas much hotter than they were evolved for) pretty much forever. Shade and water are all that's needed to achieve this goal. That seems really trivial. Is that really all you're asking about?

Comment: How have *humans* evolved to live in boreal forests?  By having the brains to wear lots of warm clothes.  What do they do when they move south?  **TAKE OFF MOST OF THE WARM CLOTHES!**

Comment: this depends a lot on how they evolved to stay warm, feathers, blubber, metabolism, fur, 
 if they have fur maybe they start shaving or cutting it short. metabolics wont need much it really depends on their anatomy.

Comment: @JBH the deserts human live in are not that much hotter than where we evolved. Drier but not much hotter. Humans have a very effective cooling mechanism.

Comment: @John Irrelevant. We didn't evolve to live in a desert. We also didn't evolve to live in Alaska or Siberia. We're capable of adapting. Ichtys' species are capable of adapting. The issue is as trivial for his species as it is for ours, which is why I'm asking if I'm missing something.

Comment: @JBH yes you are missing the obvious it is much easier to stay warm than cool off, energetically and technologically cooling is a far more difficult task. Humans have a highly efficient cooling mechanism already because we evolved in a very hot environment.  there is not place on earth humans live that is significantly hotter than what humans evolved in. just because we used technology to adapt to a much colder climate does not mean it is equally easy to adapt to a much hotter one.

Comment: @John I think you're applying extremes not in evidence. A boreal forest isn't a whole lot hotter than the African savannah. And humans live in Death Valley (47℃) where the African Savannah (30℃). Granted, it would seem that there's a significant difference between the savannah and a boreal forest (5℃)... but we're considering a delta of +17℃ to be magically less imposing than -25℃ (variant difference compared to extremes, all of 8℃). Nope. My issue remains.

Comment: @jbh the hottest average place on earth is in the African savannah, with an AVERAGE of 34 C not hottest, the average, the average for death valley is 25C. death valleys hottest recorded temperature is 57C while the hottest recorded in the African is 55C not a big difference. Even if you narrow it to recorded temperatures in current savannah distribution you still have 50C Please don't just copy paste the first answer google gives you without reading it.

Comment: @John That's beyond semantics. You're treating the African savannah like it's a hot plate. Save your insults - you've beaten this dead horse beyond recognition (and I don't recall using Wikipedia... funny, that). As stated in my first comment... shade and water. If everything were as hot as you're pretending, their blood would be boiling. *that's simply not how life works.* Rather than continuing this discussion with me, try answering the question. You obviously believe you have the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaporative cooling may be adequate.
It will cool from the current temperature to the dew point, which depends on relative humidity. In low humidity environments you can achieve very good cooling.

Place a wet towel over your head to try it out, then manufacture special 'drip shirts' for you intrepid venturers, aimed at minimising water loss while keeping them cool.

This chart from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Evaporative-Cooler-Process-on-Psychometric-Chart-where-e-Efficiency-in-percent-T-DBE_fig5_271288974) shows achievable cooling from various humidity levels.
In the case shown by the red arrow, starting at 110F and 10% humidity allows cooling to 70 F at 100% humidity. They suggest 90% of tis is achievable, but a wet garment against the skin probably manages close to 100%.

Use.
Locate curve for known humidity %.
Locate point on this curve for current temperature.
Travel up horizontal line to see temperatures at lower humidities.

[image]

---

Now you know how to use that, try this more real and useful psychrometric chart from [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/docs/documents/816/psychrometric_chart_29inHg.pdf).
Instructions [here](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/psychrometric-chart-d_816.html)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Water Cooling**

There’s a reason why swimming pools are so popular in hot regions. Humans evolved to sweat because of how efficient it is at dissipating heat. Your cold weather sophonts could dig deep water pools to cool off in during the heat of the day and keep plenty of water on hand to cool themselves with when they must work in the sun.

Answer (score 4):

**Frame challenge: They don't need to.**

Penguins and polar bears have evolved to survive in *much* colder climates than boreal forests, but they survive just fine when transported by humans to warmer climates--e.g., in zoos.

They just refrain from generating as much internal heat as they would otherwise. So, your aliens could plausibly manage just by being slightly lazier and not needing to eat quite as much as they do in their native environment. If they need additional help--stay in the shade and dig a swimming pool.

Comment: Note those are both animals that can swim and need to be supplied with water to cool off in.  without water they do  die from the heat of tropical climates.

Comment: @John Valid. But still--dig a swimming pool. That's solidly within the capabilities of a bronze-age civilization!

Comment: not really, pool water needs to be chemically treated or changed fairly frequently or it becomes a foul stagnant mess. there is a reason bathhouses in the ancient world were often the centers of a city. Also an intelligent animal needs to be able to cool off while working  not just at the end of the day.

Comment: Digging a pool is way to complicated and also unnecessary. They will just stay near natural water sources like rivers. This is something that people with bronze age technology usually have to do anyway to get a source of drinking water. These aliens need it both from drinking and swimming. Done.